# Trying to keep leading 0's in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a string that I am concatenating that comes from an auto generated number and a product code. Such as AW-003-B

="AW"&A2&C2

How do I keep the leading 0's in even past 10 and 100 etc so it doesn't become something like AW-00103-B?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
="AW"&TEXT(A2, "-000-")&C2
```